# Resizing labels in Winforms to Left

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-2.0

I have 15 to 20 labels with variable text sizes and text boxes arranged in the forms. Text boxes are arranged next to labels. The font and color of the form and hence the form controls can be configured by the user at run time. When I right align the labels and set auto grow property to true and whenever the font style changes (say from Arial to Georgia) the right aligned labels are no more right aligned.

I need a solution on labels (for winforms) to automatically grow to the left when the font size changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the anchor to "Right" rather than "Left" (you will probably also have "Top" in which case it's "Right Top" rather than "Left Top"), it should grow in the right (left) direction I believe. Been a while since I did any of this so try it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I see that now that I've had a chance to try it.

Comment: There are two solutions I see, the first is simplest and that's the ensure there is sufficient width in your label to accept the longest string you expect to see and then position it correctly with right aligned text. The second is to create a new label class inheriting from the base Label, adding an X2 or RHS int value and then overriding the OnAutoSizeChanged event to ensure that the X position for the label is adjusted accordingly when the width of the label grows.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I've more or less resolved the problem.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer to your question here to help others in the future. You can accept your own answer as the correct one too.

Comment: @nagesh46s, I wasn't saying to accept my answer. I thought you'd found a solution that resolved the problem for you, whether based on what I said or otherwise. Can *you* add that solution as an answer to your question here and accept that answer?

Answer (score 7):

Set your label properties as folowing;

```
AutoSize = false;
TextAlign = TopRight (or anything to right)
```

Then manually resize your label to a maximum area to fit your longest text. That worked for me.

Comment: Not sure why this answer hasn't had any upvotes. This is the simplest answer IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  My fix was to create a simple function to move the label, which I called after any event or code that changed the label size.

Enter the name of the label you want to grow left, and the X coordinate of the right end of the label.  Then you call this function after any changes to the label.

```
private void repositionLabel(Label lab, int endPoint)
        {
            lab.Left = endPoint - lab.Width; 
        }
```

For example,  you have a label named myLabel positioned at (75,75) and it currently has a width of 25 and you always want it to end at (100,75).  Then when this happens:

```
myLabel.Text = "blah blah blah blah blah blah";
```

you then follow the text change with:

```
repostitionLabel(myLable, 100);
```

This will make it look like the label expanded to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You could use also [RightToLeft label property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx) instead of modifying Anchor.